# How to debug docker login issue which is occurring intermittently?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-logs

When I'm trying to login to GitHub Container Registry, I'm getting below error intermittently.

```
Docker login for 'ghcr.io' failed with exit code 1
```

So, I checked the Docker Daemon logs (/var/log/messages) and I found below information on the log regarding the login failure.

```
level=info msg="Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint" error="Get \https://ghcr.io/v2/\: remote error: tls: internal error"
```

```
level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/auth returned error: Get \https://ghcr.io/v2/\: remote error: tls: internal error"
```

But I didn't get the root cause of this error. Is there any way to see more details of the error?

Answer (score 0):

You could dig through the [Go TLS source](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls) for the various instances of `alertInternalError` to see what may be triggering this issue. It would probably be easier to debug with a tool like `openssl` to verify you are really talking to GHCR:

```bash
openssl s_client -connect ghcr.io:443 -showcerts </dev/null
```

Check for the key being valid (`Verification: OK`), not expired, or any other issues.

Given that it's intermittent, my suspicion is either a flaky network dropping connections, or a proxy on the network dropping connections.

Comment: How can I check if network/proxy is dropping connections? Can you please give any commands/approach on Linux?

Comment: Network monitoring tools, proxy logs, tcpdump (at multiple points to detect when devices between the dumps are dropping).